# Nlog Dynamic FileName Archiving does not work

Tags: c#, nlog

I want to use dynamic Filenames (${shortdate}) on my logs and want to remove Logs older than x days. So this is my Nlog config:

```
<target name="All_File" xsi:type="File" filename="${basedir}/Log/${shortdate}-${machinename}-PROGRAM.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true:padding=-5}|${callsite:includeNamespace=false:padding=-45}: ${message}"
                maxArchiveFiles="1" archiveOldFileOnStartup="true"/>
```

With this configuration I should have only one logFile after the startup. But NLog is not deleting older logs.

Where am I wrong?
Using NLog 4.7.5.

Comment: NLog has the current active file (specified by the `filename="..."`), and then X number of archive-files. So `maxArchiveFiles="1"` will probably produce 2 files (1 current file + 1 archive file). See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/1479 + https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2775

Comment: Thanks, Rolf. I understand, I mixed archive and active files here.
Do you know how I can achieve this use case?   
-I dont want any archive files, just active files (with dynamic naming)
-only a certain number of active files should exist (e.g. the last 30)
   

I think this is a very easy and straightforward approach, but I cannot figure out how to do this...

Comment: There is only 1 active file. If you want to keep the last 30 files, then just specify `maxArchiveFiles="30"`.

Comment: Hi Rolf, this is exactly what I did, and it does not work for me... if i set ```maxArchiveFiles="1"```, there should be 1 active file (today) and the file of yesterday, right? I cannot get that working...

Comment: Sounds like you forgot my first comment. "NLog has current active file (specified by the `filename="..."`), and then X number of archive-files." Notice that I then responded to your other comment "only a certain number of active files should exist (e.g. the last 30)". Again there is always 1 active file, and X number of archive-files (Limited by `maxArchiveFiles`).

Comment: Thx @Rolf, I think I got it, but It does not work as i expect. But I'm going to test it on my productive system to see the effects. I think the problem is my dev environment here.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Rolf Kristensen, I got it right now.
maxArchiveFiles="1" did not work for me. I just went with

```
<target name="All_File" xsi:type="File" filename="${basedir}/Log/${shortdate}-${machinename}-PROGRAM.log"
                layout="${longdate}|${level:uppercase=true:padding=-5}|${callsite:includeNamespace=false:padding=-45}: ${message}"
                maxArchiveDays="30"/>
```

Further information: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/File-target#archive-old-log-files

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your problem.